# How to use Control.KeyUp Event in my code?

Tags: c#

I am having issue ( or lack of talent ) with my C# code. I am using this code to control Robot via bluetooth and i have it working fine when I press:
W - forward,
S - Backward,
A - Left,
D - Right,
Q - Forward Left,
E - Forward Right,
Z - Backward left,
X - Backward Right,
O - lift the robot arm,
P - Put down the arm,
N - Open the grip,
M - Close the Grip,
Y - Stop all command above,

Now these are handled through Keydown command and they work fine. The problem is that i do not know how stop any of these command when I am not pressing any of the keys. As temporary fix I have been using "Y" key which stops all actions but I am sure there is a better way to address this using keyUp or something like that.

Could you please give me just one example with maybe my command W how should i handle that if the W is not pressed anymore and i want robot to stop?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;

namespace RoverControl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MJPEGStream stream;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Declare the comands for Rover control//
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "W")     // Keyboard characeter "W" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("F");     // Passing the command "Forward" through letter "F" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover."); // Exception in the case letter "W" is pressed without connection being established//
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "S")    // Keyboard characeter "S" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("B");     // Passing the command "Backward" through letter "B" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "A")    // Keyboard characeter "A" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("L");     // Passing the command "Left" through letter "L" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "D")    // Keyboard characeter "D" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("R");    // Passing the command "Right" through letter "R" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Q")    // Keyboard characeter "Q" //
                try
                {
                serialPort1.Write("G");    // Passing the command "Forward Left" through letter "G" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "E")    // Keyboard characeter "E" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("I");    // Passing the command "Forward Right" through letter "I" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Z")    // Keyboard characeter "Z" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("H");    // Passing the command "Backward Left" through letter "H" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "X")    // Keyboard characeter "X" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("J");    // Passing the command "Backward Right" through letter "J" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "O")    // Keyboard characeter "O" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("O");    // Passing the command "Up" through letter "O" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "P")    // Keyboard characeter "P" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("P");    // Passing the command "Down" through letter "P" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "N")    // Keyboard characeter "N" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("N");    // Passing the command "Open" through letter "N" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "M")    // Keyboard characeter "M" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("M");    // Passing the command "Close" through letter "M" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "C")    // Keyboard characeter "C" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("C");    // Passing the command "" through letter "C" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "c")    // Keyboard characeter "c" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("c");    // Passing the command "" through letter "c" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "V")    // Keyboard characeter "V" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("V");    // Passing the command "" through letter "V" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "v")    // Keyboard characeter "v" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("v");    // Passing the command "" through letter "v" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "U")    // Keyboard characeter "U" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("U");    // Passing the command "" through letter "U" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "u")    // Keyboard characeter "u" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("u");    // Passing the command "" through letter "u" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Y")    // Keyboard characeter "Y" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("S");    // Passing the command "Stop" through letter "S" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
        }


            void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string IP = "";
            IP = textBox3.Text;
            stream = new MJPEGStream(IP);
            stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;
            try
            {
            stream.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid IP address.");
            }
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stream.Stop();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string COM = "";
            COM = comboBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.PortName = COM;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Please select correct Comunication Port.");
            }
        }

        private void Disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Ok so when i add the code you suggested i am still having same issue. I press W to move forward and when i release the W key it still going forward. Did I edited code wrongly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;

namespace RoverControl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MJPEGStream stream;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Declare the comands for Rover control//
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "W")     // Keyboard characeter "W" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("F");     // Passing the command "Forward" through letter "F" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover."); // Exception in the case letter "W" is pressed without connection being established//
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "S")    // Keyboard characeter "S" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("B");     // Passing the command "Backward" through letter "B" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "A")    // Keyboard characeter "A" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("L");     // Passing the command "Left" through letter "L" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "D")    // Keyboard characeter "D" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("R");    // Passing the command "Right" through letter "R" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Q")    // Keyboard characeter "Q" //
                try
                {
                serialPort1.Write("G");    // Passing the command "Forward Left" through letter "G" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "E")    // Keyboard characeter "E" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("I");    // Passing the command "Forward Right" through letter "I" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Z")    // Keyboard characeter "Z" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("H");    // Passing the command "Backward Left" through letter "H" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "X")    // Keyboard characeter "X" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("J");    // Passing the command "Backward Right" through letter "J" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "O")    // Keyboard characeter "O" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("O");    // Passing the command "Up" through letter "O" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }

            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "P")    // Keyboard characeter "P" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("P");    // Passing the command "Down" through letter "P" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "N")    // Keyboard characeter "N" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("N");    // Passing the command "Open" through letter "N" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "M")    // Keyboard characeter "M" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("M");    // Passing the command "Close" through letter "M" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "C")    // Keyboard characeter "C" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("C");    // Passing the command "" through letter "C" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "c")    // Keyboard characeter "c" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("c");    // Passing the command "" through letter "c" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "V")    // Keyboard characeter "V" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("V");    // Passing the command "" through letter "V" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "v")    // Keyboard characeter "v" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("v");    // Passing the command "" through letter "v" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "U")    // Keyboard characeter "U" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("U");    // Passing the command "" through letter "U" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "u")    // Keyboard characeter "u" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("u");    // Passing the command "" through letter "u" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
            if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Y")    // Keyboard characeter "Y" //
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("S");    // Passing the command "Stop" through letter "S" in arduino code//
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                }
        }
        void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
                try
            {
                serialPort1.Write("S");    // Passing the command "Stop" through letter "S" in arduino code//
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
            }
        }

        void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string IP = "";
            IP = textBox3.Text;
            stream = new MJPEGStream(IP);
            stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;
            try
            {
            stream.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid IP address.");
            }
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stream.Stop();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string COM = "";
            COM = comboBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.PortName = COM;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Please select correct Comunication Port.");
            }
        }

        private void Disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch KeyUp event ? (sample of code, please)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674810/how-do-i-catch-keyup-event-sample-of-code-please)

Comment: Just an annotation: I suggest to use a ```switch case``` or at least ```else if``` statements

Comment: Jules, could you give me an example for maybe just "W" forward action?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, it is not recommended to use non-realtime system to control moving things. this includes the bluetooth communication protocol and the PC itself (more specifically, Windows OS). such systems will never be able to pass any commercial or industrial tests - for obvious safety issues.

now back to your questions. what i would do is,

- define the protocol between PC and the robotic controller in a "state" manner, instead of a event-driven manner. for example, instead of sending the event that the "move forward" key has just been pressed or released, we should send the state that describes whether "move forward" key is being pressed. the robot side doesn't need to know when the key is pressed or released, it only needs to know whether it should move forward.
- on the PC side, maintain a state machine which, when in running mode, send the key state regularly, say every 10ms.
- to detect the current key state, you can either detect it directly via Keyboard.IsKeyDown() method if you use WPF, or maintain your own state with KeyUp / KeyDown events with WinForm
- on the robotic controller side, things gets relatively easy because most of them runs in a state machine manner, and that eventually you have to convert the control commands into single bit digital output to the motor or servo. and the state-based communication protocol works perfectly with this. for example, the "move forward key is being pressed" state translates directly to "turn on digital output xxx for the X axis motor".

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Calvin. I have degree in Astrophysics and you just blow my mind with all you said. :-). I am very new to robotics and especially programming part and I am working toward skills and knowledge you just demonstrated. At the moment thats bit over my head.

Comment: Annotating a bit, I knew a guy that got hurt like this.  He operated a robotic glass loader with a keyboard interface like this.  After peeling sheets of glass, he noticed a broken piece and issued the stop command to clean up.  The controller did not notice and kept the loader moving.  Caught him in the back and did the worst thing possible, it pushed his face right into the corner of the pack of glass.  It shredded his face to pieces, took 9 surgeries to put it back together.  The scars and discomfort never got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Repalce constructor:

```
        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyUp);
        }
```

then add

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {                
                if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "S" || e.KeyCode.ToString() == "W")//Check conditions
                {
                    try
                    {
                        serialPort1.Write("S");    // Passing the command "Stop" through letter "S" in arduino code//
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please establish the connection with rover.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you Jupalli. This makes sense. But where would i insert this code? After the all KeyDown logic or within after the W command?

Comment: Put it as a method like Form1_KeyDown

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested. I posted edited code up in my first post. But that doesn't work ether. Have i edited the code incorrectly?

Comment: Ok so the suggested code you provided reads, If both keys "S" and "W" are up than cast "S" to serial port1. The "S" key is backward and "W" key is forward. So if they both are up than passing the "S" - stop to serial port1?

Comment: if "S" or "W" keys are up then passing stop command to serial port

Comment: add this line in constructor if you are not ated event for key up "this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyUp);"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127863/discussion-between-slavisha-and-chandrashekar-jupalli).